# How to load pages correctly to make it work every time

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a group app and when i load the user list page, gets a bug:
*The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:*

After getting an error, I try to hot reload the page and everything works. This happens every time.

I try to download the things I need and then operate on them

```
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    groupModel =await DBFuture().getGroup(widget.groupId);
    users= await DBFuture().getUsers(groupModel.members);
    dlu=groupModel.members.length;
  }
```

```
child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: dlu,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,index) => Container(

.
.
.
.
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Nazwa: "+users[index].fullName),
                            Text("Email: "+users[index].email),
                            Text("Ranga: "),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
```

the problem is with the index?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it gives an error message with null is that your data is not loaded yet and when you reload the data is there so the error disappears.

So if you wanan get data then only build the screen you have to use a `Futurebuilder` or `StreamBuilder` for a stream. Wrap you `ListView.builder` inside a `Futurebuilder` so that it will wait for the data to be fetched then only you load the page with the data. Make sure to specify your future's return data type

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<DataType>(
      future: DBFuture().getUsers(groupModel.members),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: dlu,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) => Container(
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Nazwa: " + users[index].fullName),
                  Text("Email: " + users[index].email),
                  Text("Ranga: "),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What type of base should be

Comment: @K55 If you have found my answer helpfull/usefull. Please give it a thumbs up and mark as answer if possible ;) and as for other post in the future